# Is shrinking segment space is a nonresumable operation?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have faced a question concerning OCA exam, the question is:

```
Select the true statments about space managemnt:

a. Segment creation in oracle database 12c is deffered for all tables. There are no exeptions.
b. All UNUSABLE indexes and index partitions are created without a segment.
c. Shrinking segments space is a nonresumable operation.
d. You can set thresholds by tablespace.

Answer (according to oracle book): b, d
```

I couldn't understand why the third point (Shrinking segments space is a nonresumable operation) is not an answer.
depending on oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema002.htm#ADMIN11582

```
The resumable operation are:

-Queries
SELECT statements that run out of temporary space (for sort areas) are candidates for resumable execution. When using OCI, the calls OCIStmtExecute() and OCIStmtFetch() are candidates.

-DML
INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements are candidates. The interface used to execute them does not matter; it can be OCI, SQLJ, PL/SQL, or another interface. Also, INSERT INTO...SELECT from external tables can be resumable.

-Import/Export
As for SQL*Loader, a command line parameter controls whether statements are resumable after recoverable errors.

-DDL
The following statements are candidates for resumable execution:

CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT
CREATE INDEX
ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD
ALTER TABLE ... MOVE PARTITION
ALTER TABLE ... SPLIT PARTITION
ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD PARTITION
ALTER INDEX ... SPLIT PARTITION
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG
```

Could someone please explain me why the situation is like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank for this question. `Shrinking segments space is a nonresumable operation` as a result of my research. i.e. the answer of OCA exam question is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i thought so, but what confused me, that the answer was given inside the oracle "Administration Workshop" book, and i needed to be sure. thanks again @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on @BarbarosÖzhan research, and the book "OCA: Oracle Database 12c Administrator Certified Associate Study Guide ... By Biju Thomas" page "1101" the answer number "14", which sounds:

> ALTER TABLE … SHRINK SPACE does not create any new extents and is not resumable.

That indicates, that the answer of OCA exam question is wrong.